# How to update invoice using XERO API?

Tags: laravel, api, xero-api

I am using xero api to integrate it with my web app to manage invoices, currently i want to update invoice through invoice id, i have an helper xero.php file to handle crud operations. I have a function get invoice by invoice id, i want to update the InvoiceNumber. What is the best way to update invoice?

> update_invoice_function

```
 public function update_invoice(){
        $invoice_id = '******-***-****-****-************';

        $updated_invoice = Xero::find_invoice_by_id($invoice_id);

        $updated_invoice['response']->TotalDiscount = "1";
        $updated_invoice['response']->Date = "2020-01-20";
        $updated_invoice['response']->Status = "DRAFT";
        $get_invoice_response =   Xero::update_invoice_by_id($invoice_id,$updated_invoice['response']);
        dd($get_invoice_response);

    }
```

> update_invoice_by_id function

```
public static function update_invoice_by_id($invoice_id,$updated_invoice){

        self::instanciate();


        try{
            $update = self::$xero->loadByGUID('Accounting\\Invoice',$invoice_id);
            dd($update);
            $update->jsonSerialize($updated_invoice);

            $invoice_response = self::$xero->save($update);

            $response = [

                'error'     =>  false,

                'status'    =>  200,

                'message'   =>  'Invoice updated successfully',

                'response'  =>   $invoice_response->getElements()
            ];
        }
        catch (Exception $e){

            $response = [

                'error'     =>  true,

                'status'    =>  $e->getCode(),

                'message'   =>  $e->getMessage()
            ];
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

we have an example app that shows some sample calls to things like createInvoice.. However worth noting that there was recently a breaking change for the newer version of the API to support batch calls for invoice Create & Updates:

## Older Way

```
$result = $apiInstance->updateInvoice($xeroTenantId, $guid, $invoice);
```

## New Way

-> `updateOrCreateInvoices` is the newest way.. I recommend looking at your version of the package you are running as the function has changed.

https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2-app/blob/4bf74e915df1b0fee66f954ffcbdc331e762a06a/example.php#L1222

However - in general, doing a POST on an existing invoice with the invoice ID and the New Number will enable you to update it.

```
{
  "InvoiceID": "292532ba-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-60e7c39c4360",
  "InvoiceNumber": "INV-im-a-new-number"
}
```

[image]
Hope this un-blocks you!

Comment: I am using xero/calcinai auth 1.0

Comment: @SaadMasood - I'm not familiar with that particular project.. I'd recommend seeing if the officially supported Xero PHP sdk works for you first ( https://developer.xero.com/documentation/libraries/php )